# How to import relationships with metadata

Tags: import, relationships

I can see that I can import relationships as part of the **Contacts » Import** form, but it only seems to let me say that Contact A *is <predicate> of* Contact B.

Relationships have: start, end dates, current status ("is active"), note, title + possibly custom fields (I think). Is it possible to populate any of those via an import? Are there extensions that provide this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can heartily recommend Eileen's (obviously) Excellent "CSV API Importer" extension
[image: import screenshot- relationship options]

https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport/blob/master/README

Don't have relationship custom data on our set up so can't answer that aspect- but most other relationship fields are there

Comment: Thanks Craig, this is helpful-ish as it assumes we know the (civi or external) contact ID of the two contacts, which means its a lot of manual work to use this.

Comment: I guess with any import where you're bringing in different entities you'd have to break it into stages
1)import contacts with ext id
2) import relationships

Comment: Yes, that's a very likely expectation for a clever tech person like youself. And I don't doubt it's true. But from a user point of view, it's terrible! (1) split spreadsheet into separate sheets and make unique lists of contacts. (2) import each list of contacts separately (3) obtain their CiviCRM IDs somehow and merge back in to spreadsheet manually or risking a hideous VLOOKUP (4) Import the relationships (5) import the ... (activities/contributions/...).

Comment: Oh absolutely, it's a massive ball ache.   To use my highly developed clever tech person language.

And I hate and avoid imports for this very reason.